# Does converse of preimage theorem hold?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

[Preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem) states that if we have a smooth map $f:X\to Y$ between manifolds and $y\in Y$ is a regular value of $f$, then

1. $S = f^{-1}(y)$ is a submanifold
2. $\forall_{x\in S}T_xS = \ker(d_xf)$

From 2. follows that $\dim S + \dim Y = \dim X.$

I wonder if the converse is true.

Let $S$ be a closed submanifold of $X$ and let $Y$ be any manifold such that $\dim S + \dim Y = \dim X.$ Is there a smooth map $f:X\to Y$ and a regular value $y\in Y$ of $f$ such that 1. and 2. holds?

Comment: Generally no.  You should read the Pontriagin-Thom construction.  It gives very reasonable conditions  for the converse to hold, and the main construction also tells you how to refine your question.  The  exposition in Milnor's Differential Topology notes is very good. The central circle in a Moebius band is maybe the simplest example that shows the flaws in your setup.

Comment: The main thrust of the Pontriagin-Thom construction is that when generalizing the preimage theorem, you have to keep track of not just the preimage manifold, but its normal bundle, and how the normal bundle of the preimage relates to the normal bundle of $y$, or more generally, any submanifold of $Y$.

Comment: This is a variant of a question that occasionally pops up on MathOverflow (cf. [MO66732](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66732), [MO78209](https://mathoverflow.net/q/78209), [MO151069](https://mathoverflow.net/q/151069)). AFAIK, no answer where the converse covers all submanifolds has been given.